# Pin To Taskbar with Javapackager

Tags: windows, javafx-8, tornadofx, javapackager

When I create a javapackager native bundle of my JavaFX application via the amazing [fxlauncher](https://github.com/edvin/fxlauncher) I get it to launch with proper application icon (package/window/..icon @ 256x256) but when I pin it to taskbar it reverts to the grey Java Icon. You can see what I mean in this give. Does anyone have an idea why this is happening?

[image: Problem]

Comment: When you pin the app, it becomes a group (because it represents both the active window and the pinned app), and [the default icon for a group is the primary icon of the executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/219096/how-to-set-the-taskbar-grouping-icon). You can [customize this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8475336/changing-the-icon-shown-in-a-taskbar-group-for-a-multi-window-application).